# My mergeTwo code from coding bat should work and doesn't

Tags: java, batch-file

In the Java AP-1 section of coding bat my code is is listed-

```
public String[] mergeTwo(String[] a, String[] b, int n) {
String[] newArray = new String[n];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
if(a[i].compareTo(b[j]) < 0){
newArray[x] = a[i++];
}
else if(a[i].compareTo(b[j]) > 0){
newArray[x] = b[j++];
}
else if(a[i].compareTo(b[j]) == 0){
newArray[x] = a[i++];
}
}
return newArray;
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work. When at look at other people's code it should do the same thing but it only returns with two correct answers. When I change the else if to just else the code refuses to run. I tried it with a while loop and an int r as the index number (now it is currently x) then nothing changes. I'm just not sure what is so different. If someone could explain why I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe you also need to `j++` when `compareTo(..) == 0`?

Comment: And how is this related to `batch-file` which is only for `.BAT` files on Windows/DOS? Also, do you actually code without any indents?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're not dealing with what happens if the code runs through all of one String[] and only has numbers left in the other String[].  You need to address what happens if i or j doesn't reference a legitimate index in the string array.

Also, it seems like the parameter "n" is supposed to be the total number of strings in both arrays.  It would be better to calculate n inside the MergeTwo class:

```
public String[] mergeTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
    n = a.length + b.length;
    String[] newArray = new String[n];
```